# CSS bug with KendoUI PanelBar on IE10?

Tags: kendo-ui, internet-explorer-10, panelbar

Is there a CSS bug using KendoUI PanelBar on IE10 ? When I try [the demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/panelbar/index.html) on all other browsers, it works perfectly, but with ie10, items are shown with extra space.

any workaround ?

Comment: I tested in IE 10 and don't see that issue. Any other steps to repro this issue besides just "use IE 10"?

Comment: Hi, i'm using IE10 version 10.0.9200.16384 (update version:KB2718695) on a french Windows 8 enterprise installation. i tried again today the "Basic Usage" demo from kendoui website and have the same issue with both ie10 desktop version and modern UI version.

Comment: [Link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53687590/KendoUI_CSSIssue.png) to this.

Comment: It appears to be something that the IE Developer Tools are doing. I can replicate it by opening the dev tools. Then it won't go away. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem in that the controls were not being rendered correctly in IE10, in Chrome and Firefox and earlier versions of IE10 worked, one solution I found and resolved immediately went to update .NET Framework 4.0 for .NET 4.5, the server where the application is published must have the version 4.5 installed. I hope I have helped.